# Replace in string based on function ouput

Tags: python, regex

So, for input:

```
accessibility,random good bye
```

I want output:

```
a11y,r4m g2d bye
```

So, basically, I have to abbreviate all words of length greater than or equal to 4 in the following format: `first_letter + length_of_all_letters_in_between + last_letter`

I try to do this:

```
re.sub(r"([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]{2,})([A-Za-z])", r"\1" + str(len(r"\2")) + r"\3", s)
```

But it does not work. In `JS`, I would easily do:

```
str.replace(/([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]{2,})([A-Za-z])/g, function(m, $1, $2, $3){
   return $1 + $2.length + $3;
});
```

How do I do the same in Python?

**EDIT:** I cannot afford to lose any punctuation present in original string.

Comment: `re` is a bit of an overkill for this, in my opinion. I'd just use `mystring[0]+str(len(mystring)-2)+mystring[-1]` and an `if` statement to see when to apply this

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I thought about it but then `mystring` has separate individual words (like `accessibility,random good bye`) and not itself is a word.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke, what about the comma? How are you separating the words?

Comment: `mystring` is just one word. If you have comma separated words you can just do `mycomaseparatedstring.split(',')` to get a list of the contents of `mycomaseparatedstring` separated by commas. Then proceed as with `mystring`. Sorry, thought this was clear - it was to me because I know Python, perhaps I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're running into is that `len(r'\2')` is always `2`, not the length of the second capturing group in your regular expression. You can use a `lambda` expression to create a function that works just like the code you would use in JavaScript:

```
re.sub(r"([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]{2,})([A-Za-z])",
       lambda m: m.group(1) + str(len(m.group(2)) + m.group(3),
       s)
```

The `m` argument to the lambda is a `match` object, and the calls to its `group` method are equivalent to the backreferences you were using before.

It might be easier to just use a simple word matching pattern with no capturing groups (`group()` can still be called with no argument to get the whole matched text):

```
re.sub(r'\w{4,}', lambda m: m.group()[0] + str(len(m.group())-2) + m.group()[-1], s)
```

Comment: Very short nag that the author used `[A-Za-z]` in his original solution and that you may want to change your alternative solution to that instead of `\w`.

Comment: Accepted for giving solution as well as highlighting my issue.

Answer (score 8):

What you are doing in JavaScript is certainly right, you are passing an anonymous function. What you do in Python is to pass a constant expression ("\12\3", since `len(r"\2")` is evaluated before the function call), it is not a function that can be evaluated for each match!

While anonymous functions in Python aren't quite as useful as they are in JS, they do the job here:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]{2,})([A-Za-z])", lambda m: "{}{}{}".format(m.group(1), len(m.group(2)), m.group(3)), "accessability, random good bye")
'a11y, r4m g2d bye'
```

What happens here is that the lambda is called for each substitution, taking a match object. I then retrieve the needed information and build a substitution string from that.

Comment: @Kasra how is that? It does exactly what the author wanted and is a close analogy to his code in JS

Comment: @Kasra indeed it does. This is completely punctuation agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp, out = "",""
for ch in s:
    if ch.isspace() or ch in {",", "."}:
        out += "{}{}{}{}".format(tmp[0], len(tmp) - 2, tmp[-1], ch) if len(tmp) > 3 else tmp + ch
        tmp = ""
    else:
        tmp += ch
out += "{}{}{}".format(tmp[0], len(tmp) - 2, tmp[-1]) if len(tmp) > 3 else tmp
print(out)

a11y,r4m g2d bye
```

If you only want alpha characters use str.isalpha:

```
tmp, out = "", ""
for ch in s:
    if not ch.isalpha():
        out += "{}{}{}{}".format(tmp[0], len(tmp) - 2, tmp[-1], ch) if len(tmp) > 3 else tmp + ch
        tmp = ""
    else:
        tmp += ch
out += "{}{}{}".format(tmp[0], len(tmp) - 2, tmp[-1]) if len(tmp) > 3 else tmp
print(out)
a11y,r4m g2d bye
```

The logic is the same for both, it is just what we check for that differs, if `not ch.isalpha()`  is False we found a non alpha character so we need to process the tmp string and add it to out output string. `if len(tmp)` is not greater than `3` as per the requirement we just add the tmp string plus the current char to our out string.

We need a final `out += "{}{}{}` outside the loop to catch when a string does not end in a comma, space etc.. If the string did end in a non-alpha we would be adding an empty string so it would make no difference to the output.

It will preserve punctuation and spaces:

```
 s = "accessibility,random   good bye !!    foobar?"
def func(s):
    tmp, out = "", ""
    for ch in s:
        if not ch.isalpha():
            out += "{}{}{}{}".format(tmp[0], len(tmp) - 2, tmp[-1], ch) if len(tmp) > 3 else tmp + ch
            tmp = ""
        else:
            tmp += ch
    return "{}{}{}".format(tmp[0], len(tmp) - 2, tmp[-1]) if len(tmp) > 3 else tmp
print(func(s,3))
a11y,r4m   g2d bye !!    f4r?
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative precise way you can use a separate function for `re.sub` and use the simple regex `r"(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)"`.

```
>>> def replacer(x): 
...    g=x.group(0)
...    if len(g)>3:
...        return '{}{}{}'.format(g[0],len(g)-2,g[-1])
...    else :
...        return g
... 
>>> re.sub(r"(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)", replacer, s)
'a11y,r4m g2d bye'
```

Also as a pythonic and **general** way, to get the replaced words within a list you can use a list comprehension using `re.finditer` :

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> rep=['{}{}{}'.format(i.group(0)[0],abs(sub(*i.span()))-2,i.group(0)[-1]) if len(i.group(0))>3 else i.group(0) for i in re.finditer(r'(\w+)',s)]
>>> rep
['a11y', 'r4m', 'g2d', 'bye']
```

The [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) will returns a generator contains all [`matchobjects`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) then you can iterate over it and get the start and end of `matchobject`s with [`span()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span) method.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple...

```
>>> s = "accessibility,random good bye"
>>> re.sub(r'\B[A-Za-z]{2,}\B', lambda x: str(len(x.group())), s)
'a11y,r4m g2d bye'
```

`\B` which matches between two word characters or two non-word chars helps to match all the chars except first and last.

Comment: Excellent! Never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and comprehension:

```
import re
s = "accessibility,random good bye"
print "".join(w[0]+str(len(w)-2)+w[-1] if len(w) > 3 else w for w in re.split("(\W)", s))
```

*Gives:*

```
a11y,r4m g2d bye
```

Comment: This will abbreviate any four-or-more character long run of non-word characters. Try `s='foo... bar'` to see for yourself!

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the following code

```
sentence = "accessibility,random good bye"
sentence = sentence.replace(',', " ")
sentence_list = sentence.split(" ")
for item in sentence_list:
    if len(item) >= 4:
        print item[0]+str(len(item[1:len(item)-1]))+item[len(item)-1]
```

The only thing you should take care of comma and other punctuation characters.